# How can I see if and where execution reaches a certain file in python?

Tags: python, debugging

I'm trying to debug a server that raises a 404 error. I do not know where that 404 error is raised, but I can take a guess at a few files where it might be raised from. These files have dozens of methods inside and I can't figure out which specific method the error is being raised from. Is there any way to find that out? Knowing if execution even reaches those files might be helpful.

Comment: what are you using as a web framework? Django, flask, etc?? They usually have a debug option which when set to True prints the traceback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot catch the moment when execution reaches a file, because it actually happens when the file is imported.

I would suggest using `ipdb`/`pdb++`. In every method/function of the file put (after doing `pip install ipdb` or `pip install pdbpp`):

```
import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

So when execution gets to this line, you can debug you server analyzing stacktrace (enter `w`).

You can also use built-in `pdb`, but `ipdb`/pdb++` is nicer.

Or you can set a break-point with `ipdb` in a request entry point and follow the execution using `n`, `s`, `r`, etc. You can find more info on using `pdb`/`pdb++`/`ipdb` in Internet.